# Problems with Input and output regarding Java String

Tags: java, string, input

Well Hello,
I´m trying to program a kind of game in my free right now.
I started coding some time ago in school but recently we didn´t do much with java so I thought I should do something, so that I don´t forget everything. Well, I still need some since we never did something that's kind of like this. My Problem is that it shows an error and tells me an symbol is missing. The program is supposed to start the game and later interact with different types of objects that contain character information such as stats for both monsters and the player.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Spiel{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("What is your name Adventurer?\n ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);
        String Abenteurername = scanner. nextLine();
        System.out.println("Adventurer "+Abenteurername+" will you help us clean the dungeon? \n");
        String Spielstart = scanner. nextLine();
         
        if (Spielstart.equalsIgnoreCase(ja)) {
            System.out.println("Gut");   
        } else {
            System.exit(0);  
        } // end of if-else
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please indent correctly your code so that it's readable. Also which line is raising the error?

Comment: `ja` is defined nowhere

Comment: Thanks i simply forgot the "" for ja which means kind of yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote `ja` without quotes, it expects to find a variable defined with that name, like

```
String ja = "ja";
if (Spielstart.equalsIgnoreCase(ja)) {
    System.out.println("Gut");
}
```

But what you want is just

```
if (Spielstart.equalsIgnoreCase("ja")) {
    System.out.println("Gut");
} else {
    System.exit(0);
} // end of if-else
```